# git rebase always use current branch file version for conflicts

Tags: git

I want to go from

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

to

```
              A--B--C topic
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

i.e. do a rebase but for every conflict take what the file looks like in A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
git checkout topic
git rebase -s recursive -X theirs master
```

Comment: This wasn't perfect (I had to manual fix a removed file but worked)

Comment: @jpiasetz I'm not so sure that `ours` was the correct strategy to use in this case, since the two sides are reversed in a `rebase`, compared to a `merge`.

Comment: This worked for me `git rebase -s recursive -X theirs master` followed by a few `git add . --all && git rebase --continue` as well as having to manually delete some misc file prior to the final push.